# Single choice and multiple choice questions helper sentences

Tags: american-english, terminology, vocabulary, sentence, sentence-patterns

I am trying to find the more appropriate helper sentences, e.g. for a single choice question:

> "check" only one of the options
>   **OR** "check" only one of the answers

Is there a better way to say this!?

Also, for multiple-choice questions:

> You can "check" more than one option **OR** You can "check" more than one answer

Can I replace the word "check" with something better? 
is it ok if I say "Select" instead! I'm open to your suggestions

P.S. this is in a questionnaire context, in a mobile app

Comment: It would be helpful to have a screenshot of what you are asking about. For example, is it _checkboxes_ that need to be _checked_ or text of some sort? This may be a question that is better answered by a UX expert.

Comment: More concise: "Only one answer allowed", "Multiple answers allowed"

Comment: Note that normally the term "multiple-choice question" simply means that there is a list of possible answers to choose from, even when only one answer can be selected. I understand the distinction you're trying to make, but I've never heard the term "single-choice question" before.

Comment: Select one of the options...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Choose* or *check* is fine.

Use *may* instead of *can* here.

You may check **one** answer.

You may check **one or more** answers.

Or use underlining for boldface.

Answer (score 1):

The word select is just fine; however you might consider the word "populate".  This word can be used in multiple choices, short answers and to give any feedback.  This is best on an online format.

Comment: I think 'populate' relates to a more arbitrary and larger scale filling in than opting or selecting does.

Answer (score 1):

You can say:

**Mark the correct answer(s)**

OR

**Which of the following is/are correct?**